# How to connect my Tryton client to the remote tryton server?

Tags: tryton

I am biginner with tryton so accept my request. My situation is: I install a tryton server in my remote server production and I install my tryton client in my localhost. My question is: can I connect to the remote server with my tryton client? if yes. I need to know how to do this. Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can connect to a remote server. Thinks to take in account:

1. Your server should be configured to listen to public ip. See http://doc.tryton.org/3.6/trytond/doc/topics/configuration.html?highlight=listen#listen
2. Ensure that there is no firewall blocking communication

Once done that, you can connect to remote server introducing the host and the port of the server in the client dialog. Have a look at:

http://tryton-documentation.readthedocs.org/en/latest/user_guide/tryton_client.html#connecting-to-your-server

Comment: BTW, if you post to tryton mailing list you will normally have more replies than here. And of course, there is no need to post on both places :)

Comment: Hello, i configure my server like this:

[database]
uri = postgresql://gnuhealth:password@adress_of_my_server/
path = /home/gnuhealth/attach
[jsonrpc]
listen = *:8000
data = /home/gnuhealth/gnuhealth/server/tryton
[session]
super_pwd = vpxI0qPULzoMU

But when i enter the connection parameters of my server in tryton's login window and i try to connect to the remote server, it show me the following error:
error connection: bad username and password

Please help me thanks in advance

Comment: This is because your credentieals are invalid or the database doesn't exists

Comment: You have to initialitze it with tryton server. See http://doc.tryton.org/3.6/trytond/doc/topics/setup_database.html#initialize-a-database

Comment: You have to run the initialize database on the server, so the trytond executable will be available

Comment: It seems that there is some error on the config file.

Comment: Hello, thanks for your reply.When i try to initialize my database on the server using this command: trytond -c /home/gnuhealth/gnuhealth/tryton/server/config/trytond.conf -u res -d <mydatabase_name> , it show me this error: File "/usr/bin/trytond" line 111, in <module>   trytond.server.trytonServer(options).run()  File"/home/gnuhealth/gnuhealth/tryton/server/trytond-3.4.4/trytond/server.py line 27  in _init _  config.update_etc(options.configfile)  AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'configfile'  .  Please help me to resolve this problem.